# Webpack Custom resolve dependency based on d.ts of compiled bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, webpack

this is the first time i ask a question on stackoverflow, so i apologize in advance if i write something strange and thanks everyone for the help.

I have implemented a modular solution based on Asp.Net MVC 5, TypeScript 2.2.0 and Angular 4.0.0 compiled with Webpack 3.0.0. 
It has a Main application (MVC) that must host external Modules that are other MVC applications with own backend Web Apis and own Angular components.

My goal is to compile and deploy single module without having source code of others Modules or Main app source code, but using just compiled bundles and definitely types.
In this way i can deploy only my module (bundle.js and dlls) in append to the main application.

The process should be:

1. Compile Main App
2. Deploy on Server
3. Compile Module1
4. Copy bin dll on Main App bin
5. Copy Module1 js bundle on Main App scripts folder

and so on...

I'm just able with webpack to compile single module and resolve same names using last generated "records.json" file.

The problem is when i want to use a component of other module. I have to import class using d.ts generated from other module:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/module1.d.ts" />
import { HttpWrapperService } from "Module1/App/http-wrapper/http-wrapper.service";
```

But when Webpack encounter import statement it can't resolve module because there is no source code of http-wrapper.service, and return this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Module1/App/http-wrapper/http-wrapper.service' in 'C:\svn\AngularApp\Module2\App\users'
```

How can i tell to Webpack to resolve the module name imported from d.ts using "records.json" file?
Maybe with a plugin?

Solution has a structure like this:

```
Root
|--- Main (MVC App)
|     |
|     |--- Manifest.js
|     |--- Vendor.js (bundle of all third party libraries like Angular or jQuery)
|     |--- Polyfills.js
|     |--- App.js (bundle of main app)
|
|--- typings
|     |
|     |--- app.d.ts
|     |--- module1.d.ts
|     |--- module2.d.ts
|
|--- Module1
|     |
|     |--- App
|           |
|           |--- http-wrapper
|                 |
|                 |--- http-wrapper.service.ts
|
|--- Module2
      |
      |--- App
            |
            |--- users
                  |
                  |--- users.component.ts
                  |--- users.service.ts
```

Comment: this theme is new for me, but I thought main module should contain new ones. You should have one main module and from it build hierarchical dependent structure, isn't it?

Comment: thanks for reply :), modules are lazy loaded by routing, so they don't depend on others. The only dependency is for common components like http-wrapper.service on the sample above.